# IE 8 line height issue

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

I am having weird height issues only in IE8

http://www.jobs-apollo.com/job/details/San-Francisco-CA/EnrollmentMarketing/national-advisor-workforce-solutions-10845/

I'm not sure why, but there's an extra line break at the bottom of each paragraph.  Can someone please look into this issue and help me out to see why that is?

Thanks

Comment: Please check site in firefox, too, your source (in firefox - wrong html is marked red), and you will see.

Comment: You have `<br>` tags and `<span id="HRS_SCH_PSTDSC_DESCRLONG$2" class="PSLONGEDITBOX">` I assume this mess is from a WYSIWYG editor? Markup the text properly with `<p>` tags. Also your bullet points aren't an `unordered list`. Make sure everything is semantically correct in terms of HTML markup.

Answer (score 1):

Spans aren't a good way to lay out your content, especially when you need to put margins and padding on them.

For one thing, a span is an "inline" element, and shouldn't have margin or padding put on it because inline elements are meant to be displayed on the "line" instead of block-level elements, which cause automatic line breaks after they are closed.

http://www.impressivewebs.com/difference-block-inline-css/

You should fix your html to look like this if you can, as it is more semantically correct and is less likely to break in older browsers. You may also want to consider putting padding on your

tags instead of margin, as I have found that margins are much more finicky in IE than padding.

```
                <p id="HRS_SCH_PSTDSC_DESCRLONG$0" class="PSLONGEDITBOX">Apollo Group, Inc. was founded in 1973 in response to a gradual shift in higher education demographics from a student population dominated by youth to one in which approximately half the students are adults and over 80 percent of whom work full-time. Apollo's founder, John Sperling, believed -- and events proved him right -- that lifelong employment with a single employer would be replaced by lifelong learning and employment with a variety of employers. Lifelong learning requires an institution dedicated solely to the education of working adults.</p>
                <p>Today, Apollo Group, Inc., through its subsidiaries, University of Phoenix, Apollo Global, College for Financial Planning, and Institute for Professional Development, has established itself as a leading provider of higher education programs for working adults by focusing on servicing the needs of the working adult. Apollo Group is the largest education service provider in North America and has the world's largest educational social network. Apollo is building state of art learning platforms in creating a virtual and highly engaging learning experience. The learning platforms which are built as a cloud based (Education-as-a-Service) bring a more scientific and social approach to the learning experience. We are changing the way people learn and interact via advanced, scalable learning solutions.</p>
                <strong>Subsidiary Statement</strong></p>
```

Also, anywhere you use a "b" tag for bold you should replace it with "strong" as the "b" tag has been deprecated. This may also be part of your problem, as the  tag may have hidden inherent styles on it that IE is using.

Once you improve your code to be more standards compliant, you may find that it works better. I can't see in Firefox exactly what's causing the problem, but my suspicion is that these spans with margins and br tags plus deprecated "b" tags isn't helping your case here.

**Finally and most importantly, you need to fix the extra doctype and head tags that are actually INSIDE of your container div. This is certainly causing some issues:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the replies.  I'm not sure that anything can be done to replace the <span> tags with <p> as those are all brought in through their own aggregator service into that site.  Thanks in regard to the duplicated <html> declaration though, not sure where that came from.. It's been removed.  I've added span.PSLONGEDITBOX {
    display: block !important;
} but it didnt seem to fix it in IE.

Comment: hrm. Well I'm still not sure what's causing it, but I would try to also zero out the margin and padding on all b tags like this and see if it helps:

    b {margin:0 padding:0;}

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, your problem is that you're using `<span>` tags to demarcate paragraphs. Use the `<p>` (paragraph) tag for paragraphs. That will probably fix everything. You can half-fix some of your issues by making your `<span>` into `display:block` in your CSS:

```
span.PSLONGEDITBOX {
  display: block;
}
```

This will fix some of those weird hanging last lines. But I'm not convinced it will fix all of them.

The proper fix is to completely eliminate all those `<span>` and `<br>` elements. If you properly use `<p>` for paragraphs, and `<h1>` through `<h5>` for headings, you will never need to manually insert a `<br>`, or at least very infrequently. Don't use `<b>` tags for headings. That's not what they are for.

PS: This is broken in IE9 and IE10 as well.

Comment: I see that you added my CSS--that fixed the hanging-last-line at the end of the `<span>`, but within the span it doesn't fix the text that is followed by `<br>`. To properly fix this you really need to be able to change the HTML as the `<br>` is what's messing it up and you can't fix it with CSS. Your only other solution would be to use Javascript to dynamically edit the DOM and correct the HTML. If you are looking for a solution that doesn't involve changing any HTML or using any Javascript, I don't think there is one.

Comment: Thanks again for your reply. Okay so I was able to somehow change <span> wrapper to <p> but it still didn't change it in IE... but in regard to your <br> stuff, what would you reccomend I change if I could?  Not sure where the <br> would be causing issues.

Comment: Most of your `<br>`s can be replaced with `</p><p>`, in other words, the `<br>` is being used to separate paragraphs, and that's what the `<p>` tag is for.